# POST in form is not getting called in django project

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

After the FamilyForm is Filled and redirect the PersonForm is not get post. they are two forms to fill. adding action to the form also didn't trigger it. there might be something small that has been missed in it. please help as soon as possible

for any other information tag and let me know

**View.py**

```
def index(request):
familyForm = FamilyForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    familyForm = FamilyForm(request.POST)
    if familyForm.is_valid():
        familydetails = familyForm.save()
        return redirect(addPerson,familydetails.familyId)
        #return render(request, 'html/personForm.html',{"family":familydetails,'personForm':personForm})
return render(request, 'html/index.html', {"familyForm": familyForm})

def addPerson(request,FamilyID):
    family = FamilyDetails.objects.get(familyId=FamilyID)
    personForm = PersonForm()
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        personForm = PersonForm(request.POST)
        print(personForm.errors)
        if personForm.is_valid():
            personDetails = personForm.save(commit=False)
            print(personDetails)
            return HttpResponse("<h1>Form FIlled</h1>")
    return render(request,'html/personForm.html', {"personForm":personForm, 'family':family })
```

**personForm.html**

```
    {% extends 'html/familyCard.html' %}
    <div class="formRepeat">
        <form method="post"  action="{% url 'add_person' family.familyId %}" id="personForm"  class="needs-validation" novalidate
              data-qualification-url="{% url 'ajax_load_qualification' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
```

**urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('addperson/<int:FamilyID>/', views.addPerson, name="add_person"),
    path('ajax/load-qualification/',views.load_qualification,name='ajax_load_qualification'),
]
```

Comment: Use - ```return redirect('add_person',familydetails.familyId)``` in your ```index``` view. You must pass a ```url``` name (a string) here.

Answer (score 0):

i think that in redirecting the user to (add_person) page you made mistake

return redirect("add_person", familydetails.familyId) but you wrote function name instead url name

Comment: didn't work sorry. the function is getting called but after form is filled the post method isn't getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your html

```
{% url 'add_person' FamilyID=family.familyId %}
```

or

```
{% url 'add_person' FamilyID.family.familyId %}
```

maybe one of this can help you

Comment: didnt work. the problem is in the form i think. cause that function is getting called properly.

Comment: try removing   novalidate
              data-qualification-url="{% url 'ajax_load_qualification' %}" from your form and see if it's work or not

Comment: if that didn't work, try using return redirect after if form.is_valid(): and use else before return render, make sure the indent of return render is for else

Comment: in your form you have this method="post" , type post like this = 'POST" all capital